# Turkey chili from raw in a slow cooker accidentally for 10 hours on warm

Tags: food-safety, slow-cooking, crockpot, chili, organic

Just woke up and realized the turkey chili (2 cans kidney beans, 1 can black beans, 2 cans diced tomatoes, 1 lb turkey ground) had been cooking from raw on warm for 10 hours.

I'm a bit desolate since it's all organic. I just turned it to high and set a timer for 4 hours. Can my chili still be salvaged?

This isn't a duplicate to this [wiki](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-know-if-food-left-at-room-temperature-is-still-safe-to-eat) because it is specific to chili crockpot with the ingredients above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I know if food left at room temperature is still safe to eat?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-know-if-food-left-at-room-temperature-is-still-safe-to-eat)...certainly, the info you need is in this question.  You would need to know the temperature of "warm" in your slow cooker.

Comment: I appreciate your edit, but the ingredients are irrelevant.  It is the temperature and time that are the critical variables.

Comment: Do you mean it was on the slow-cooker's "low" setting, or does yours also have a "keep warm" setting?

Comment: It has a keep warm, low, and high

Comment: Well it just says warm